# Probability of an even function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

given the function:
[image]

why does:
[image]

does the fact that it's an even function has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|X_2|>\epsilon$ if $X_2>\epsilon$ or $X_2<-\epsilon$.  So 
$$P(|X_2|>\epsilon)=\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}f_2(x)\,dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}f_2(x)\,dx
=-\int_{\infty}^{\epsilon}f_2(-u)du+\int_\epsilon^\infty f(x)dx,$$ that is, $$P(|X_2|>\epsilon)
=\int_\epsilon^\infty f_2(-u)du+\int_\epsilon^\infty f(x)dx
=\int_\epsilon^\infty f_2(u)du+\int_\epsilon^\infty f(x)dx,$$ and finally, $$P(|X_2|>\epsilon)
=2\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}f_2(x)\,dx
=2\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}|x|^{-3}\,dx$$
To get the identity in the second displayed line, I used the fact that $f_2$ was even.

Comment: Small detail, but it is true only for  $ |\epsilon| \geq 1$.